# Can't attach debugger (GDB) to Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, arm, gdb, qemu

I'm playing around with the code from the "Embedded Programming with Android: Bringing Up an Android System from Scratch" book.
The Android versions meant in the book are a bit outdated, like 4.4, so I decided to use the current ones.
My setup is:

- Debian 11
- emulator 31.2.10
- android 24/armeabi-v7a system image
- gcc-arm-none-eabi (15:8-2019-q3-1) for compiling the sources
- gdb-multiarch(10.1.90)/arm-none-eabi-gdb (10.3-2021.10) for debugging

Emulator command is `emulator -verbose -show-kernel -netfast -avd avd_name -shell -qemu -s -S -kernel test_binary.axf`

The problem is that the both GDB versions (gdb-multiarch set to arm, armv7 or whatever and arm-none-eabi-gdb) fail to attach to the running emulator.
So, the `target remote localhost:1234` command fails with the following error message:

```
warning: while parsing target description (at line 1): Could not load XML document "arm-core.xml"
warning: Could not load XML target description; ignoring
Truncated register 16 in remote 'g' packet
```

Why this error happens (given the latest, quite widely used tools and no special setup it should work out of the box)? Is there any additional GDB or emulator/QEMU settings to tweak?

Can someone share a working configuration for the emulator in ARM mode on x86_64?

EDIT: Also the following error happens: `qemu-system-armel: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'`. Installing previous emulator versions doesn't seem to help.

Comment: try to install ADB in your system.

Comment: I have the same problem, are you solved it?